# When you talk to/ you talking to.. do both parts mean the same thing in the given context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I don't like it **when you talk to** other people more than you talk
>   to me.
>
> I don't like **you talking to** other people more than you talk to me.

Are both the sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: I feel that, although they are both correct, the second one sounds 'dumber'. As in, it's more casual and not as formal or 'smarter' than the first. It sounds like to different characters in a book saying the same thing. But yeah, there is no difference at all.

Answer (score 1):

They're both grammatical, they're both natural, and I can't find a noticeable difference in their meanings.